# how to attach a div container to top of map marker in google map javascript api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can i attach a div container which containing custom title and other information to top of map marker in google map JavaScript API

**Look like this:**
[image: div container to top of map marker]

**Note:**

- Container should be visible all time (if marker visible).
- Containershould move with marker.
- Container should not visible outside of map frame.

**My API configuration:**

```
<div id="locMap"></div>
<script>    
    function initMap() {

                var Loc = {lat: 10.914912, lng: 75.925752};
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('locMap'), {
                  zoom: 12,
                  center: Loc
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: Loc,
                  map: map
                });

              }
</script>
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  i am updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Map Info windows
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows
and
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

 var contentString = '<div id="content"><h1 id="firstHeading">Welcome</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<p><b>Hello</b>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
```

Comment: info window did't works for me. because its only visible when click on marker. but i need it always visible

Comment: I just updated the code appending the following line:-
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

Answer (score 1):

try to attach the use google maps infowindow element to the gmaps marker , api here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: info window did't works for me. because its only visible when click on marker. but i need it always visible